# conn.prepareStatement throws an error

Tags: java, servlets

I am working on a WEB project and I want to enable for the user to register ,so after the user write his details(username,password,nickname,...)  I want to check if the username or the nickname he entered are unique(don't exist in the Users table),so in the servlet i wrote:

```
try {

        Context context = new InitialContext();
        BasicDataSource ds = (BasicDataSource) context
                .lookup(getServletContext().getInitParameter(UAppConstants.DB_DATASOURCE) + UAppConstants.OPEN);
        Connection conn = ds.getConnection();

        PreparedStatement stmt;
        try{
            System.out.println("1");

            stmt = conn.prepareStatement(UAppConstants.SELECT_USER_BY_NICKNAME_STMT);

            System.out.println("2");

            stmt.setString(1, _nickname);
            //here some other code

           }catch (SQLException e) {
                System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            }
    //here some other code


}
catch (SQLException | NamingException e) {
        getServletContext().log("Error while closing connection", e);
        response.sendError(500);// internal server error
    }
```

UAppConstant.java:

```
    public final String SELECT_USER_BY_NAME_STMT = "SELECT * FROM USERS " + "WHERE username=?";
    public final String SELECT_USER_BY_NICKNAME_STMT = "SELECT * FROM USERS" + "WHERE nickname=?";
```

and in the sql table there is columns username,nickname.

the problem is that it prints 1 in the console but it never prints 2 ,instead ,it prints:

```
Syntax error: Encountered "=" at line 1, column 34.
```

I looked over all the "=" in the servlet and all of them are in right syntax!

Thanks for helpers:)

Comment: Add the complete stacktrace please

Comment: Try inserting spaces around the '='

Comment: how can I do that? @Jens

Comment: @shery Just copy the whole Exception around the "Syntax error" Message

Comment: @desperateCoder there are spaces

Comment: "SELECT * FROM USERS" + "WHERE nickname=?" -> you are concatenating users and where without space. try: "SELECT * FROM USERS" + " WHERE nickname=?"

Comment: @desperateCoder that's the solution , thank you so so much :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably forgot to specify the parameter number in your prepare statement template. So **PreparedStatement** is unable to figure out which parameter to set in place of **?**. Also " " is missing between **USERS** and **WHERE**

So, instead of:

```
"SELECT * FROM USERS" + "WHERE nickname=?"
```

You should write:

```
"SELECT * FROM USERS " + "WHERE nickname=?1"
```

And similarly, instead of:

```
"SELECT * FROM USERS " + "WHERE username=?"
```

You should write:

```
"SELECT * FROM USERS " + "WHERE username=?1"
```

Comment: you are also missing a space between 'users' and 'where' in the first statement (nickname)

Comment: @shery If it worked, kindly accept and upvote my answer.

Comment: @shery Or more seriously, simply `"SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE username = ?"` since there is no need to concatenate two constant String ;)